# What is the difference between notable_for and notable_types property?

Tags: freebase, mql

I see that there are both `/common/topic/notable_types` and `/common/topic/notable_for` properties in the topic dump of Freebase.

What is the difference between these two? I am assuming that both are providing the notable types of a topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect. `notable_for` can be things other than types - e.g. Justin Bieber (`/m/06w2sn5`) is notable for being a singer-songwriter (`/m/016z4k`) which is a profession rather than a type. Also, `notable_types` is multi-valued whereas `notable_for` is single-valued.

Comment: Thanks Philip! That helps a lot!

Comment: @Philip Kendall "notable_for" can have anything other than types right? When you say **notable_types** is **multi-valued** meaning that a **subject** can have **multiple notable_types** whereas **one and only** one **notable_for**